# rails 3 routes: different auto route for model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

so i've got a model class named Photoset and a controller named Sets.
ive got resources :sets working for everything except when paths are generated off an instance of the model. for example if i use:

```
<%= form_for(@photoset) do |f| %>
```

i get the error:

```
 no route matches {:controller=>"sets"}
```

ultimately i want all the uris to be .../sets/...(controller name)  instead of .../photosets/...(model name)

is there any way to do this and still be able to use the helpers?

**--EDIT--**
heres my rake routes output:

```
    sets GET    /sets(.:format)          {:controller=>"sets", :action=>"index"}
         POST   /sets(.:format)          {:controller=>"sets", :action=>"create"}
 new_set GET    /sets/new(.:format)      {:controller=>"sets", :action=>"new"}
edit_set GET    /sets/:id/edit(.:format) {:controller=>"sets", :action=>"edit"}
     set GET    /sets/:id(.:format)      {:controller=>"sets", :action=>"show"}
         PUT    /sets/:id(.:format)      {:controller=>"sets", :action=>"update"}
         DELETE /sets/:id(.:format)      {:controller=>"sets", :action=>"destroy"}
```

that all works just dandy, the problem is when i try to build a form off an instance of the model.  I understand that rails has no way of knowing that im trying to tie the Photoset model directly with the Set controller, but I don't know how to specify that.

Comment: Can you show `rake routes` output?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have a Photoset model, Sets controller and urls need to be in form `/sets/1/edit`.

```
resources :sets, :as => "photosets"
```

Works with a simple form like this:

```
<%= form_for(@photoset) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
    <%= f.submit "Save" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: keeping all this functionality same, is there a way to change it so that just the urls are different? instead of `/photosets/1/edit` could i make it `/sets/1/edit` ? I still want to use `form_for(@photoset)` but i want it to point to `/sets/...`.

Answer (score -1):

You should set

```
resources :photosets, :as => "sets"
```

which allow you to use `photosets_path`, `photoset_path`, `new_photoset_path`, etc... but shows the url as `sets`

See [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) if you need more info

Comment: this changes the helpers from photoset_path to set_path unfortunately the urls are all still /photoset . check section 4.3 of the routing guide link you posted.